# Install a Plugin in GeckoFX

Tags: plugins, drm, geckofx

Hay, im making a browser and want to attatch a Plugin to my Geckofx browser.
I simply looked how widevine was installed in firefox and made it like that. I copyed the gmp-widevinecdm from the firefox-profilefolder to the  profile folder of my browser.

I experimented with these flags and configs

```vb
            GeckoPreferences.Default("extensions.blocklist.enabled") = False
            GeckoPreferences.Default("media.gmp-manager.updateEnabled") = True
            GeckoPreferences.Default("media.gmp-widevinecdm.version") = "4.10.1582.2"
            GeckoPreferences.Default("media.gmp-widevinecdm.abi") = "x86_64-msvc-x64"
            GeckoPreferences.Default("media.gmp-widevinecdm.enabled") = True
            GeckoPreferences.Default("media.gmp-widevinecdm.visible") = True
```

I simply want to implement DRM-support and really dont know anymore what to do :/

:)

Comment: Try to place the plugin in the root folder of your browser. https://bitbucket.org/geckofx/geckofx-45.0/issues/86/plugin-containerexe-crashing-application

Comment: @wp78de That has not solved it.

Comment: although it is an old thread but can anybody tell me was it solved ?

Comment: No,  it wasn't, sorry.

Comment: then how did you make it up ?